# Paste the calendar into the menu in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a menu in tkinter, in which there will be different conditions. One of them will be the date choice. Now you need to enter the date manually. I want to make a calendar. I thought to use the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774089/python-calendar-widget-return-the-user-selected-date) and the code to which there is a link. But I do not know how to use it with my code.

Below is the code of my menu:

```
import numpy as np
items5 = np.arange(1,14)
items6 = np.arange(1, 28)
items7 = np.arange(4, 28)
choose_y_n = ['yes', 'no']
items12 = np.arange(50, 100)
items13 = np.arange(0,15)

from tkinter import*

class MyOptionMenu(OptionMenu):
    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):
        self.var = StringVar(master)
        self.var.set(status)
        OptionMenu.__init__(self, master, self.var, *options)
        self.config(font=('Arial',(10)),bg='white',width=20)
        self['menu'].config(font=('Arial',(10)),bg='white')


root = Tk()

optionList5 = items5
optionList6 = items6
optionList7 = items7
optionList8 = choose_y_n
optionList12 = items12
optionList13 = items13

lab = Label(root, text="Enter the date in the format 'dd.mm.yyyy'", font="Arial 10", anchor='w')
ent1 = Entry(root,width=20,bd=3)
lab5 = Label(root, text="condition №1", font="Arial 10", anchor='w')
mymenu5 = MyOptionMenu(root, '2', *optionList5)
lab6 = Label(root, text="condition №2", font="Arial 10", anchor='w')
mymenu6 = MyOptionMenu(root, '12', *optionList6)
lab7 = Label(root, text="condition №3", font="Arial 10", anchor='w')
mymenu7 = MyOptionMenu(root, '13', *optionList7)
lab8 = Label(root, text="condition №4", font="Arial 10", anchor='w')
mymenu8 = MyOptionMenu(root, 'yes', *optionList8)
lab12 = Label(root, text="condition №5", font="Arial 10", anchor='w')
mymenu12 = MyOptionMenu(root, '80', *optionList12)
lab13 = Label(root, text="condition №6", font="Arial 10", anchor='w')
mymenu13 = MyOptionMenu(root, '9', *optionList13)

labels = [lab, lab5, lab6, lab7, lab8, lab12, lab13]
mymenus = [ent1, mymenu5, mymenu6, mymenu7, mymenu8, mymenu12, mymenu13]

def save_selected_values():
    global values1
    values1 = [ent1.get(), mymenu5.var.get(), mymenu6.var.get(), mymenu7.var.get(), mymenu8.var.get(),
               mymenu12.var.get(), mymenu13.var.get()]
    print(values1)


def close_window(): 
    root.destroy() 

button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=save_selected_values)
button1 = Button(root, text="Quit", command=close_window)

for index, (lab, mymenu) in enumerate(zip(labels, mymenus)):
    lab.grid(row=index, column=0)
    mymenu.grid(row=index, column=1)
    button.grid(row=index, column=2)
    button1.grid(row=index, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

For me, it's important to save the date in a variable.

I will be very grateful for any recommendations!

**UPD**
My new code is below.

It seems that my code doesn't save the date at all.

I just don't understand how to get the date as a variable. What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
items5 = np.arange(1,14)
items6 = np.arange(1, 28)
items7 = np.arange(4, 28)
choose_y_n = ['yes', 'no']
items12 = np.arange(50, 100)
items13 = np.arange(0,15)

from tkinter import*
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import ttk

def get_calendar(locale, fwday):
    # instantiate proper calendar class
    if locale is None:
        return calendar.TextCalendar(fwday)
    else:
        return calendar.LocaleTextCalendar(fwday, locale)

class Calendar(ttk.Frame):
    # XXX ToDo: cget and configure

    datetime = calendar.datetime.datetime
    timedelta = calendar.datetime.timedelta

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        """
        WIDGET-SPECIFIC OPTIONS

            locale, firstweekday, year, month, selectbackground,
            selectforeground
        """
        # remove custom options from kw before initializating ttk.Frame
        fwday = kw.pop('firstweekday', calendar.MONDAY)
        year = kw.pop('year', self.datetime.now().year)
        month = kw.pop('month', self.datetime.now().month)
        locale = kw.pop('locale', None)
        sel_bg = kw.pop('selectbackground', '#ecffc4')
        sel_fg = kw.pop('selectforeground', '#05640e')

        self._date = self.datetime(year, month, 1)
        self._selection = None # no date selected

        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kw)

        self._cal = get_calendar(locale, fwday)

        self.__setup_styles()       # creates custom styles
        self.__place_widgets()      # pack/grid used widgets
        self.__config_calendar()    # adjust calendar columns and setup tags
        # configure a canvas, and proper bindings, for selecting dates
        self.__setup_selection(sel_bg, sel_fg)

        # store items ids, used for insertion later
        self._items = [self._calendar.insert('', 'end', values='')
                            for _ in range(6)]
        # insert dates in the currently empty calendar
        self._build_calendar()

        # set the minimal size for the widget
        self._calendar.bind('<Map>', self.__minsize)

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        if item in ('year', 'month'):
            raise AttributeError("attribute '%s' is not writeable" % item)
        elif item == 'selectbackground':
            self._canvas['background'] = value
        elif item == 'selectforeground':
            self._canvas.itemconfigure(self._canvas.text, item=value)
        else:
            ttk.Frame.__setitem__(self, item, value)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item in ('year', 'month'):
            return getattr(self._date, item)
        elif item == 'selectbackground':
            return self._canvas['background']
        elif item == 'selectforeground':
            return self._canvas.itemcget(self._canvas.text, 'fill')
        else:
            r = ttk.tclobjs_to_py({item: ttk.Frame.__getitem__(self, item)})
            return r[item]

    def __setup_styles(self):
        # custom ttk styles
        style = ttk.Style(self.master)
        arrow_layout = lambda dir: (
            [('Button.focus', {'children': [('Button.%sarrow' % dir, None)]})]
        )
        style.layout('L.TButton', arrow_layout('left'))
        style.layout('R.TButton', arrow_layout('right'))

    def __place_widgets(self):
        # header frame and its widgets
        hframe = ttk.Frame(self)
        lbtn = ttk.Button(hframe, style='L.TButton', command=self._prev_month)
        rbtn = ttk.Button(hframe, style='R.TButton', command=self._next_month)
        self._header = ttk.Label(hframe, width=15, anchor='center')
        # the calendar
        self._calendar = ttk.Treeview(show='', selectmode='none', height=7)

        # pack the widgets
        hframe.pack(in_=self, side='top', pady=4, anchor='center')
        lbtn.grid(in_=hframe)
        self._header.grid(in_=hframe, column=1, row=0, padx=12)
        rbtn.grid(in_=hframe, column=2, row=0)
        self._calendar.pack(in_=self, expand=1, fill='both', side='bottom')

    def __config_calendar(self):
        cols = self._cal.formatweekheader(3).split()
        self._calendar['columns'] = cols
        self._calendar.tag_configure('header', background='grey90')
        self._calendar.insert('', 'end', values=cols, tag='header')
        # adjust its columns width
        font = tkFont.Font()
        maxwidth = max(font.measure(col) for col in cols)
        for col in cols:
            self._calendar.column(col, width=maxwidth, minwidth=maxwidth,
                anchor='e')

    def __setup_selection(self, sel_bg, sel_fg):
        self._font = tkFont.Font()
        self._canvas = canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self._calendar,
            background=sel_bg, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        canvas.text = canvas.create_text(0, 0, fill=sel_fg, anchor='w')

        canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda evt: canvas.place_forget())
        self._calendar.bind('<Configure>', lambda evt: canvas.place_forget())
        self._calendar.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self._pressed)

    def __minsize(self, evt):
        width, height = self._calendar.master.geometry().split('x')
        height = height[:height.index('+')]
        self._calendar.master.minsize(width, height)

    def _build_calendar(self):
        year, month = self._date.year, self._date.month

        # update header text (Month, YEAR)
        header = self._cal.formatmonthname(year, month, 0)
        self._header['text'] = header.title()

        # update calendar shown dates
        cal = self._cal.monthdayscalendar(year, month)
        for indx, item in enumerate(self._items):
            week = cal[indx] if indx < len(cal) else []
            fmt_week = [('%02d' % day) if day else '' for day in week]
            self._calendar.item(item, values=fmt_week)

    def _show_selection(self, text, bbox):
        """Configure canvas for a new selection."""
        x, y, width, height = bbox

        textw = self._font.measure(text)

        canvas = self._canvas
        canvas.configure(width=width, height=height)
        canvas.coords(canvas.text, width - textw, height / 2 - 1)
        canvas.itemconfigure(canvas.text, text=text)
        canvas.place(in_=self._calendar, x=x, y=y)

    # Callbacks

    def _pressed(self, evt):
        """Clicked somewhere in the calendar."""
        x, y, widget = evt.x, evt.y, evt.widget
        item = widget.identify_row(y)
        column = widget.identify_column(x)
        self.event_generate("<<CalendarChanged>>")

        if not column or not item in self._items:
            # clicked in the weekdays row or just outside the columns
            return

        item_values = widget.item(item)['values']
        if not len(item_values): # row is empty for this month
            return

        text = item_values[int(column[1]) - 1]
        if not text: # date is empty
            return

        bbox = widget.bbox(item, column)
        if not bbox: # calendar not visible yet
            return

        # update and then show selection
        text = '%02d' % text
        self._selection = (text, item, column)
        self._show_selection(text, bbox)

    def _prev_month(self):
        """Updated calendar to show the previous month."""
        self._canvas.place_forget()

        self._date = self._date - self.timedelta(days=1)
        self._date = self.datetime(self._date.year, self._date.month, 1)
        self._build_calendar() # reconstuct calendar

    def _next_month(self):
        """Update calendar to show the next month."""
        self._canvas.place_forget()

        year, month = self._date.year, self._date.month
        self._date = self._date + self.timedelta(
            days=calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1] + 1)
        self._date = self.datetime(self._date.year, self._date.month, 1)
        self._build_calendar() # reconstruct calendar

    # Properties

    @property
    def selection(self):
        """Return a datetime representing the current selected date."""
        if not self._selection:
            return None

        year, month = self._date.year, self._date.month
        return self.datetime(year, month, int(self._selection[0]))


class MyOptionMenu(OptionMenu):
    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):
        self.var = StringVar(master)
        self.var.set(status)
        OptionMenu.__init__(self, master, self.var, *options)
        self.config(font=('Arial',(10)),bg='white',width=20)
        self['menu'].config(font=('Arial',(10)),bg='white')


root = Tk()

optionList5 = items5
optionList6 = items6
optionList7 = items7
optionList8 = choose_y_n
optionList12 = items12
optionList13 = items13

lab = Label(root, text="Select date", font="Arial 10", anchor='w')
ent1 = Calendar(firstweekday=calendar.SUNDAY)
lab5 = Label(root, text="condition №1", font="Arial 10", anchor='w')
mymenu5 = MyOptionMenu(root, '2', *optionList5)
lab6 = Label(root, text="condition №2", font="Arial 10", anchor='w')
mymenu6 = MyOptionMenu(root, '12', *optionList6)
lab7 = Label(root, text="condition №3", font="Arial 10", anchor='w')
mymenu7 = MyOptionMenu(root, '13', *optionList7)
lab8 = Label(root, text="condition №4", font="Arial 10", anchor='w')
mymenu8 = MyOptionMenu(root, 'yes', *optionList8)
lab12 = Label(root, text="condition №5", font="Arial 10", anchor='w')
mymenu12 = MyOptionMenu(root, '80', *optionList12)
lab13 = Label(root, text="condition №6", font="Arial 10", anchor='w')
mymenu13 = MyOptionMenu(root, '9', *optionList13)

labels = [lab, lab5, lab6, lab7, lab8, lab12, lab13]
mymenus = [ent1, mymenu5, mymenu6, mymenu7, mymenu8, mymenu12, mymenu13]

def save_selected_values():
    global values1
    values1 = [ent1, mymenu5.var.get(), mymenu6.var.get(), mymenu7.var.get(), mymenu8.var.get(),
               mymenu12.var.get(), mymenu13.var.get()]
    print(values1)

def on_calendar_changed(event):
    date = cal.selection
    datestr = "{:%d.%m.%Y}".format(date)
    print(datestr)
    dateVar.set(datestr)

def close_window(): 
    root.destroy() 

button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=save_selected_values)
button1 = Button(root, text="Quit", command=close_window)

for index, (lab, mymenu) in enumerate(zip(labels, mymenus)):
    lab.grid(row=index, column=0)
    mymenu.grid(row=index, column=1)
    button.grid(row=index, column=2)
    button1.grid(row=index, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

That `ttkcalendar.py` needs a little help I reckon. You want to perform an action when the calendar widget has a new date selected and to do that you should bind to an event. However it is not generating any at the moment so at the end of the `_pressed` method add the following line to generate a virtual event you can bind to:

```
self.event_generate("<<CalendarChanged>>")
```

You can then add this widget to your UI and bind a function to this `CalendarChanged` virtual event as shown:

```
def on_calendar_changed(event):
    date = cal.selection
    datestr = "{:%d.%m.%Y}".format(date)
    print(datestr)
    dateVar.set(datestr)

cal.bind("<<CalendarChanged>>", on_calendar_changed)
```

Here I set a StringVar named `dateVar` as the textvariable of the `ent1` widget. Now when the calendar selection changes, it puts the properly formatted string into your entry widget.

You would do well to convert from the `OptionMenu` widget to `ttk.Combobox` widgets and generally use ttk widgets in preference to the older Tk widgets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I'm having trouble understanding how to use `on_calendar_changed` and how to get the date as a variable. Could you please write in more detail, what should I do? In the question, I added my updated code.